# get form field name (that appears in the form), not actual name in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

If I have a simple form, something like:

```
 <div class="main_account">
 <form name="create_account" action="create_account.php" method="post">

                <legend>Create Account</legend>
                <p><label for= "user" >Username*: </label><br/><input type="text" name="user" />
                <p/>
                <p><label for= "password" >Password*: </label><br/><input type="password" name="password" />
                <p/>
..........
```

Is there a way to see in the create_account.php form the "Username*:" value for the name field,in other words the value that appears next to each form field in the actual field. I am asking this because I want to create a field that displays a variable string next to it, and I don't know how to pass it to php script. I am not interested in include or require.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No, that information is not passed through the form. You'll need to store it somewhere else if you want to use it later.

Comment: How can I store it somewhere else?

Comment: you can store them in <input type="hidden" name="user2" value="Username*" />